# Gradle command syntax for executing TESTNG tests as a group

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, automated-tests, testng

I have some tests as below:

```
@Test(groups={"smoke"})
public void Test1(){...}

@Test(groups={"smoke", "regression"})
public void Test2(){...}

@Test(groups={"regression"})
public void Test3(){...}
```

In build.gradle file I have below:

```
task smoketests(type: Test){
useTestNG() {
   suites "src/test/resources/testng.xml"
   includeGroups "smoke"
}
```

}

I need to have a gradle syntax to run the smoke/regression tests only using commandline. 
I have tried this:

```
./gradlew clean test -P testGroups="smoke"
```

if I run that, build is successful as below:

```
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 42.253 secs
```

But it never execute actual tests.  Need help

Comment: (Why is this tagged with git?)

Answer (score 0):

You have created a custom test task, so you need to use that instead of `test` in your command line:

```
gradlew clean smoketests
```